# JSON RPC Data Structure

Tags: json-rpc

Is there a data structure that contains all the JSON RPC endpoints? Not the wiki, but a JSON or SQL file that I can use to programatically iterate over all the endpoints to generate code.

Comment: How many details do you want for each endpoint? It's dead simple to generate a list of just the names, but a totally different story to add (unopinionated) details.

Comment: I need the id, name and parameters.